# Jquery: Count node separation in xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm loading an xml document using JavaScript (Jquery `$.ajax`).

I need to be able to count the number of branches (b) separating 2 text nodes (s).

E.g.

```
    <b n="Archaea">
        <s>Archaea</s>
        <b n="Eubacteria">
            <s>Cyanobacteria</s>
            <s>Spirochaete</s>
            <b n="Seaweeds">
                <s>Red rags</s>
                <s>Calliblepharis</s>
            </b>
        </b>
        <b n="Land plants">
            <s>Liverwort</s>
            <s>Moss</s>
            <s>Bracken fern</s>
            <b n="Seed plants">
                <s>Scots pine</s>
                <s>Ginko</s>
                <s>Welwitschia</s>
            </b>
        </b>
    </b>
```

So, how many branches is 'Scots pine' away from 'Calliblepharis', for example. In this case, the answer would be 4 (Seed plants > Land plants > Archaea > Eubacteria > Seaweeds).

I also need to calculate the 'closest common ancestor' between 2 elements. For example, between 'Scots pine' and 'Ginko' it would be 'Bracken fern' (because Bracken fern is the closest species to the branch that contains 'Scots pine' and 'Ginko'). I'm really not sure how this would work when the 2 elements are very far from each other in different branches.

Sorry if I'm using the wrong language here. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: If you were to calculate how many branches 'Scots pine' is away from 'Calliblepharis', what would the answer be?

Comment: It'd be 4 branches away, I think. Seed plants > land plants > Archaea > Eubacteria > Seaweeds. 4 steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the late reply.

I've set up a a demo at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ofiqi3/4)

Hopefully it's fairly self explanatory but if not ask me.

For the xhr bit you need to have an `file.xml` in the same directory as the page.

This is the main function that gets the distance between the branches

```
    function elementDistance(elem1, elem2) {
        var steps = 0;
        //the parent elements are the branches
        var first = elem1.parentElement;
        var second = elem2.parentElement;
        //if the elements are at different depths you need to even them up
        //and count each time as a step
        if (elem1.depth() > elem2.depth()) {
            while (first.depth() > second.depth()) {
                first = first.parentElement;
                steps++;
            }
        }
        else if (elem1.depth() < elem2.depth()) {
            while (first.depth() < second.depth()) {
                second = second.parentElement;
                steps++;
            }
        }
        while (first !== second) {
            steps += 2;
            first = first.parentElement;
            second = second.parentElement;
        }
        return steps;
    }
```

p.s. the demo doesn't work in firefox or IE

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and detailed example. I've yet to get the xhr function to work, but I'll look into it more. 

Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem :-) The xhr function just works with an xml file containing the example you gave, it's just a simple demonstration of loading the xml file and selecting two random nodes and calculating their distances.